# Should I replace all img elements with the canvas element?

Tags: html, image, canvas

I'm new to the canvas element of html5. I'm specifically wondering when you should put an existing img element inside of a canvas element.

What's the benefit or appropriate use of this?

I've been reading [Dive into HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html) and didn't quite get what I was looking for in their concluding statement on the topic of canvas:

> The simple answer is, for the same reason you might want to draw text
>   on a canvas. The canvas coordinates diagram included text, lines, and
>   shapes; the text-on-a-canvas was just one part of a larger work. A
>   more complex diagram could easily use drawImage() to include icons,
>   sprites, or other graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image tag is best used for a static piece of imagery.

Canvas is, to quote the HTML5 working group, "a resolution-dependent bitmap canvas which can be used for rendering graphs, game graphics, or other visual images on the fly."

So, you can slap an image onto a canvas, but that is probably to augment some other piece of work you're creating, like a chart or a game graphic.

**UPDATE AFTER YOUR UPDATE**

So, if you want to create a really complex chart that tracks stock performance in real-time, you could use the canvas to draw the various bars of the graph, and then also use drawImage() to place company logos on the canvas to indicate which bar belonged to which bar.

Comment: Ahh okay I think this is making more sense. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem. If it helped, please feel free to mark as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Where `img` does the job, use that. `canvas` is a very powerful tool indeed, but:

1. While it's supported by a large portion of browsers today, `img` is still much more widely supported.
2. If you need to cater to users with JavaScript disabled, `canvas` cannot be used; `canvas` needs JavaScript to operate, whereas `img` doesn't.

That said, if you need something that only `canvas` can do, feel free. For example:

- Do you need to load an image and then let users warp it or draw on it? A `canvas` would do quite nicely there.
- Do you need to dynamically draw some charts and graphs? `canvas` would work well there, too.

When you have no need for the more advanced capabilities of `canvas`, though, and just need to display images, `img` is the most obvious and compatible choice.

Comment: I see - I think that helps. Have you ever, personally, had a need for placing an image in canvas?

Comment: @Carolann: Not on its own, no. I have placed an image in a canvas to then access and modify the pixel data, but not purely to display the image unmodified.